# AJAX y php, no encuentra el indice en la tabla

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

estoy haciendo el intento para desplegar informacion de una tabla que tengo en mi base de datos con AJAX y PHP. Estoy haciendo la busqueda con el numero de ID. La pagina que tiene el script `XMLHttpRequest` es esta:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function consulta(){
            var p = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var id = document.getElementById("i").value;
            var url = "ajaxphp.php";
            var vars = "id="+id;
            
            p.open("POST", url, true);
            
            p.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlenconded");
            
            p.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(p.readyState == 4 && p.status == 200){
                    var respuesta = p.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = respuesta;
                }
            }
            
            p.send(vars);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="i" name="id">
    <button id="enviar" onClick="consulta()">Listo</button>
    <span id="info"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

El fichero que contiene el script PHP es este:

```
<?php
    require('conexion.php');
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $consulta = "SELECT FROM nuevosingresos WHERE id = '$id'";  
    mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
?>
```

Cuando ejecuto la funcion me aparece este error por parte de la consola de PHP:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\sistemacapa\ajaxphp.php on line 3
```

los indices que estoy utilizando estan registrados en la tabla, pero aunque los ponga me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje de error. ¿Que esta mal?

Comment: En `p.setRequestHeader()` es `urlencoded` en lugar de `urlenconded`, te sobra la `n`.

Comment: Gracias, lo acabo de corregir y ya no me sale el mensaje de error, pero no pasa nada, todavia no se ha podido arrelgar.

Comment: Saludos Te sugiero un **echo** a **$_POST** y **$_GET**; para checar si en algunas de ellas llega el **id** que esperas recibir (esa forma que usas no la he usado; yo uso el **$.Ajax** de *jQuery**). Si ninguna la tiene, entonces algo te falta para enviarlo.

Comment: Te faltan las columnas en la consulta, prueba con `SELECT * FROM`. Preferentemente usa una consulta preparada.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr Roberto, acabo de agregar la linea de ```echo $id;``` y fijate que si esta tomando el valor que meto en el input. Entonces, que sera lo que esta pasando??

Comment: Habiendo corregido lo que te han dicho los compañeros, ahora te falta extrar el resultado de la consulta y devolverlo al cliente, te estás quedando en `mysqli_query()`  y punto, pero falta: 1. Verificar si esa consulta es exitosa, leer sus resultados y devolverlos / imprimirlos (revisa al respecto los métodos  fetch de mysqli)  o 2. Verificar si la consulta fue errónea y devolver un mensaje de error.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. El mensaje que compartes a mi parecer hace referencia a la línea del php `$id = $_POST['id'];`; tal que, `$consulta ="....";` no se ejecuta; por ello mi sugerencias revisar si llega ese elemento en `$_POST` *(este que es el único arreglo que usas)* y `$_GET` *(y este el otro arreglo que pudiera contenerlo)*; adicionalmente que la sentencia SQL `$consulta` está incompleta *(pero no es aquí donde se genera el error a mi parecer, es antes)*.

Comment: @A.Cedano Buenas noches. Ya le agregue la linea para ver los errores; puse la funcion ```mysqli_error()``` de esta forma: ```mysqli_error($consulta);``` y me dice que: ```Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\wamp64\www\sistemacapa\ajaxphp.php on line 7``` Que espera que sea una cadena de caracteres.

Comment: Pues sí, parece que tenemos error, PERO, a `mysqli_error` debes pasarle la conexión, no la consulta, o sea: `mysqli_error($conexion);`

Comment: @A.Cedano Cuando estaba pensando en agregarle la funcion ```mysqli_error()``` tenia el presentimiento de que no debia de pasarsela porque si se la pasaba no me iba a salir nada, pero de todas formas ya se la pase y ya no me aparece ningun error, entonces, no estoy 100% seguro pero creo que si se estan conectando al servidor. Me salio este mensaje de error: ```Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\wamp64\www\sistemacapa\ajaxphp.php on line 8```

Comment: Nada te podemos decir si no vemos cómo estás usando `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, por favor pulsa en [edit] y coloca cómo tienes ahora el código.

Comment: ```<?php
 require("conexion.php");
 $id = $_POST["id"];
 echo $id;
 $consulta = "SELECT * FROM nuevosingresos WHERE id = '$id'";
 mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
 mysqli_error($conexion);
 mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
?>```

Comment: Lo debes pasar a `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` es el recurso que te devuelve `mysqli_query()`, no la cadena con la instrucción SQL. No sé si me explico, `mysqli_query` devuelve un recurso y `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` es uno de los métodos que existen para leer ese recurso. Ponlo así: `$mData=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mData)) {
        var_dump($row);
    }` Ahí deberás ver un dump de todas las filas, a no ser que haya otro error. Te recomiendo que leas las explicaciones del Manual de PHP de aquellas funciones que quieras usar y que revises los ejemplos

Comment: Buen dia Reverendo, ya puse el codigo y si, efectivamente me esta desplegando todo lo que coincide con el numero de ID asi ```C:\wamp64\www\sistemacapa\ajaxphp.php:12:
array (size=6)
  'id' => string '26' (length=2)
  'nombre' => string 'Franco Almaraz Jose Andres' (length=26)
  'usuario_spark' => string 'joseaa' (length=6)
  'contra_spark' => string '******' (length=6)
  'numero_estacion' => string '135' (length=3)
  'extension_msip' => string '1058' (length=4)```